# How and where to use/place database queries when a webform is submitted?

Tags: 7, database, webforms

Let's say that I already created a **webform** with fields **Customer Name**, **Customer Surname** and **Customer Address**.

When the webform is submitted, I want to insert those values captured in a custom table "**Customer**" created in the database that Drupal is using.

How do I achieve this? Do I have to use a specific module to insert those values?

Is it feasible to do this by using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module? If yes, can you give me a simple example on how to do this?

Comment: Are you aware that Webform module will store submissions in a table called webform_submissions by default?

Comment: I'm aware of that the data are stored in the submissions but you can also clear all of them. I wanted to find a way to insert data from a webform into a custom table. My goal is to use several tables linked through relationships for a booking system. It'll be hard to retrieve all data from only the webform_submissions table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_webform_submission_insert to insert data in custom table

ie :

```
function hook_webform_submission_insert($node, $submission) {
  // Insert a record into a 3rd-party module table when a submission is added.
  db_insert('mymodule_table')
    ->fields(array(
    'nid' => $node->nid, 
    'sid' => $submission->sid, 
    'foo' => 'foo_data',
  ))
    ->execute();
}
```

As mentioned in above example you will find all submitted data in

```
$submission
```

variable.

Comment: In the webform module, I added the following db_insert line of codes: **db_insert('test')->fields(array(array(
    'Name' => $node->webform['components'][1]['value'], 
 'Surname' => $node->webform['components'][2]['value'],

  )) ->execute();** within the webform_webform_submission_insert function. It adds a record with empty values.  The values of webform['components'][..]['value'] had been checked using **devel** module. Do you have any idea for this behaviour?

Comment: @Joey, i checked with devel : You have to use $submission->data[1][0] value in your insert query instead of  $node->webform['components'][1]['value'].

Comment: I used $submission->data[1]['value'] and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @visabhiushek Where did you check to obtain those values on devel?

Comment: @Joey, i have used dsm($submission) and dsm($node) in hook_webform_submission_insert to check the values. There i find $node->webform['components'][1]['value'] is empty and $submission->data[1][0]  contains the exact value what we want.